# Smoothing sympy plots

Tags: python, plot, sympy

If I have a function such as `sin(1/x)` I want to plot and show close to 0, how would I smooth out the results in the plot? The default number of sample points is relatively small for what I'm trying to show.

Here's the code:

```
from sympy import symbols, plot, sin

x = symbols('x')
y = sin(1/x)

plot(y, (x, 0, 0.5))
```

[image]

As `x` approaches 0, the line becomes more jagged and less "curvy". Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the number of points used manually:

```
plot(y, (x, 0.001, 0.5), adaptive=False, nb_of_points=300000)
```

[image]

<sub>Note: I expected to get ZeroDivisionError when using the exact question-code  (that is, having x go from 0 to something), but i don't get an error (strange). I *do* get the error though as soon as I use `adaptive=False, nb_of_points=300000`, so this is why I set xmin to a non zero value (`0.001`).</sub>

Comment: I guess the adaptive algorithm needs to be improved. The whole point of it is to automatically handle cases like this.