# Why am I getting different plots for each run of same Python SymPy plotting code?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

My code (Linux Mint 21.2, Python 3.10):

```
import sympy
print(sympy.__version__) # '1.9'
from sympy import symbols, sin
from sympy.plotting import plot
t = symbols('t')
plotP = plot(  50*sin(t/30)+30*sin(1.3*t/30)+20*sin(2.7*t/30)+25*sin(3.7*t/30), (t, 24800 , 35800) )
```

Four different runs, four different plots:

[[image: Plot_1] [image: Plot_2] [image: Plot_1] [image: Plot_4]

*What could be the reason for getting this confusing results?*

============

ADDED to clarify that the issue occurs also when the script is executed from a shell:

[image: Plot_5]

============

ADDED to show that upgrading to newest versions of sympy and matplotlib did not solve the issue:

[image: Plot_6]

By the way: I can't reproduce the issue with much smaller intervals like for example 0 to 400 - in this case the diagrams are all the same. The difference: the "steady" diagrams consist of a nice smooth curve without overlapping peaks because of putting a very large interval with peaks much nearer to each other than the distance of the pixels in the display.

Comment: where are you executing your code? standard python interpreter? interactive shell? jupyter notebook? visual studio code?

Comment: @Davide_sd : I am usually running it from Textadept text editor command line, but see my updated question for evidence that it also occurs if run from the shell command line. Have you failed to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue. Which matplotlib version are you using?

Comment: >>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'3.5.1'

Comment: >>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'3.8.2'
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'1.12'
 ::: but still the same issue ...

Comment: @Davide_sd : what does the diagram look like on your system? Every time exactly the same diagram? Have you run my code on your system?

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior (Windows, Pycharm, sympy 1.12).  Probably related to how sympy's plotting implements adaptivity. For some weird reason, the behavior disappears when I replace the pesky floats with fractions.  As in `50*sin(t/30)+30*sin(13*t/300)+20*sin(27*t/300)+25*sin(37*t/300)`.

Comment: The randomness in explicitly mentioned in the [sympy plotting docs](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/SymPy/part1.html#plotting-function-reference). "The plotting uses an adaptive algorithm which samples recursively to accurately plot the curve. The adaptive algorithm uses a random point near the midpoint of two points that has to be further sampled. Hence, repeating the same plot command can give slightly different results because of the random sampling."

Comment: @JohanC does setting `adaptive=False` in the plot command fixes this weird behavior?

Comment: Yes, see [smoothing synpy plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399145/smoothing-sympy-plots): `plot(..., adaptive=False, nb_of_points=300000)`

Comment: @Claudio with Sympy 1.12 (and previous versions), the diagram looks different everytime you run the plot command, because by default the plotting module uses an adaptive algorithm, with a random "init". To get consistent results you have to manually set "adaptive=False". Starting with SymPy 1.13 (still to be released), the plotting module will use `adaptive=False` by default...

Comment: @JohanC : the weird behavior actually disappears with `adaptive=False` set. If you like put this and the explanation into an answer I would like to accept, so that this question can be considered answered. OK ... I have started with sympy today ... and immediately run into this trouble - really hard to guess how it comes. It's sure a good idea to make `adaptive=False` the default, but ... on the other side, the from run to run changing diagram is a hint, that what is shown is not really the data. Maybe a good idea to write a warning about it to the console?

Comment: @JohanC : changing the code to fractions did not help on my machine. Setting `adaptive=False` did :) . Thanks! It was really mind boggling for me. That plotting is using random values is really something I would for sure not expect. It does not make any sense to me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to the issue with `adaptive=True` ( the weird behavior actually disappears with `adaptive=False` ) mentioned already in the comments to your question :

> The randomness in explicitly mentioned in the [sympy plotting docs](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/SymPy/part1.html#plotting-function-reference). "The plotting uses an adaptive algorithm which samples recursively to accurately plot the curve. The adaptive algorithm uses a random point near the midpoint of two points that has to be further sampled. Hence, repeating the same plot command can give slightly different results because of the random sampling." – JohanC Feb 9 at 12:19

you become a victim of a probably widespread wrong beginner expectation that the shape of the plot you see has always something to do with the shape of the function you are plotting.

This expectation is the main reason why you were surprised to see some strange artifacts in the periodic sinus function plots like straight lines over a longer period of time and in combination with the adaptive algorithm used in sympy for choosing the sampling points you experienced random changes of the plotted curve, which was not the expected representation of the underlying function values, but some kind of random result depending on choice of the section on time axis anyway.

In other words, *YOU have the responsibility* to know that if you use a fast changing periodic function of `t` and use then a too large timeline period, what you see in the plot, even if it looks like a periodic curve, is nothing else as some by chance of choosing the start and end time obtained more or less arbitrary values connected to each other to form a curve in the plot. So what you actually see in the plot has as good as nothing to do with the actual shape of the curve of the function you are plotting.

I encourage you to play with `nb_of_points` parameter you can pass to the plot method. The lower the assigned to it value, like for example: `nb_of_points=7` the more what you see has as good as nothing to do with the function you are plotting. In other words you will be getting very different plots depending on the value you use for `nb_of_points`. Try it out and see for yourself.

Below an example of using your code with different values for `nb_of_points=` to illustrate the above explanations:

[image: Plot_51-52__59]

Further reading: [Smoothing sympy plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399145/smoothing-sympy-plots)